# unable to display count on the barchart (svg graph)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am currently working on a stacked barchart using only svg, html and css and no third party library is used for this.

Please refer to this codepen https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/qBXvzQd

As per the stacked barchart, the data gets displayed properly but the count of each bar is not displayed.

the data used for this stacked barchart is as follows

```
const data = [
    {
      name: 'Transit',
      passed: 2,
      skipped: 5,
      failed: 22,
      untested: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Access',
      passed: 0,
      skipped: 0,
      failed: 0,
      untested: 100
    }
  ];
```

As per this data, i am trying to display count 2 (for `passed`) ,5 (for `skipped`) , 22 (for `failed`) and 100 (for `untested`)

Can someone please let me know how to display these counts on their respective barcharts. To be clear, i want to display count on the barchart similar to the one shown in the below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `<text>` element into your bar group.

```
      return (
        <g key={Math.random()}>
          <rect
            width={50}
            height={`${height}%`}
            fill={bar.color}
            x={60} // multiply with the width (50) + 10 for space
            y={`${y}%`}
          />
          <text
            x={70}                // visible centre point of your bar
            y={`${y + height/2}%`}
            dy="1.3em"            // adjusts the text y position to adjust for
                                  // text descenders. Makes the vertical centring 
                                  // more accurate. Normally 0.3 to -0.35, but has 
                                  // an extra ~1em because of the 180deg rotate.
            textAnchor="middle"   // centre the text horizontall at x
            class="bar-label"     // styling for this text
            >{`${bar.value}%`}</text>
        </g>
      );
```

```
.bar-label {
  fill: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

This change is complicated a little by the fact that you've rotated your bar SVGs by 180deg.  That causes the text to be upside down. So I have to flip each `<text>` element back upright.

Comment: LeBeay- Thanks for the solution. have i complicated the bar graphs ? do you suggest a better approach to display the bars ?

Comment: Having the rotate transform complicates adding the text a bit. But if you are happy now, then you don't need to change it. But I would have just done the "flipping" by adjusting the bar segment's Y coordinate. Also, I probably wouldn't have chosen to have individual SVGs for each bar. I would have put them all in one SVG.

Comment: i am finding it difficult to put all under one svg. can you suggest how to do it

Comment: Here's a start.  I haven't done the bottom labels, but I think there is enough there that you can work out how to do that. https://codepen.io/PaulLeBeau/pen/PoKrOgN

Comment: Thank you. this is very helpful

Comment: the bottom labels are getting tricky. Can you check if you are able to add the bottom labels please

Comment: I've updated my codepen to add the X axis labels.