# difficult to put code in one svg (svg graph)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I have been working on a stacked barchart for quite some time and i think i have a messy code where i had used `<svg>` at 2 places for this one chart.

Please refer to this codepen https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/dyzEvMG I tried putting it under one svg tag so that the code looks lot sorted and better but i am unsuccessful. Any number of iterations to put the code in one svg tag has resulted in either messing up with the code even more and sometimes the barchart doesnot show up at all with my changes.

Can someone please let me know how to fix this mess i created. Would really appreciate any inputs on this.

The most important mess is the below code where i had put svg for each individual barchart.

```
{entries.map((entry, indx) => (
        <div class="mGraph content-style" key={Math.random()}>
          <svg
            viewBox={`0, 0, 80, 450`}
            height={500}
            width={90}
            style={{ transform: `rotateX(180deg)` }}
          >
            {rows(entry)}
          </svg>
          <div class="x-title">{entry.name}</div>
          { indx === 1 && <text class="label-title">PROJECTS</text>}
        </div>
))}
```

I tried reorganizing the code and here is the codepen for it
https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/NWvZGLd

Comment: ***how to fix this mess i created*** can you be more specific?

Comment: @kiner_shah- sorry, if i wasnt clear. i meant two svgs for 1 graph makes the code look complicated n messy. Wanted to know how do i clean up and make usage of only one svg

Comment: Did you trying appending the rows to the graph SVG?

Comment: @kiner_shah- i did try that but the bars didnt show up when i made that change.

Comment: Maybe you should post the complete code within the post along with what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried this way https://codepen.io/a166617/pen/NWvZGLd

Comment: You seem to have a `div` inside SVG. What happens if `div` is removed?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, I provided an answer to this in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70062686/1292848)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau- could you pls post your codepen as an answer here so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do it using plain JS. Was able to create a single SVG for the graph:

```js
const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

const addLine = (parent_g, x1, x2, y1, y2) => {
  var line = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "line");
  line.setAttribute("x1", x1);
  line.setAttribute("y1", y1);
  line.setAttribute("x2", x2);
  line.setAttribute("y2", y2);
  parent_g.appendChild(line);
};

const addText = (parent_g, x, y, text_val, class_ = "", dy = "", textanchor="", transform="") => {
  var text = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "text");
  text.setAttribute("x", x);
  text.setAttribute("y", y);
  
  if (class_ !== "")
    text.classList.add(class_);
  
  if (dy !== "")
    text.setAttribute("dy", dy);
    
  if (textanchor !== "")
    text.setAttribute("textAnchor", textanchor);
    
  if (transform !== "")
    text.setAttribute("transform", transform);
    
  text.innerHTML = text_val;
  parent_g.appendChild(text);
};

const addRect = (parent_g, width, height, x, y, fill) => {
    var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect");
    rect.setAttribute("width", width);
    rect.setAttribute("height", height);
    rect.setAttribute("x", x);
    rect.setAttribute("y", y);
    rect.setAttribute("fill", fill);
    parent_g.appendChild(rect);
};

const addBarsToGraph = (entries) => {
  const barWidth = 50;
  const maxBarHeight = 490;
  
  var svgGraph = document.getElementById("svg-graph");
  
  var xpos = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
  {
    //console.log(entries[i].bars);
    for (var j = 0; j < entries[i].bars.length; j++)
    {
        const height = (entries[i].bars[j].value * maxBarHeight) / entries[i].total;
        const y = maxBarHeight - height - ((entries[i].bars[j].y * maxBarHeight) / entries[i].total);
        //console.log(height, y);
        addRect(svgGraph, 50, height, xpos, y, entries[i].bars[j].color);
        addText(svgGraph, xpos + 15, y + height / 2 - 10, entries[i].bars[j].value, "bar-count", "1.3em", "middle");
    }
    //console.log(xpos, maxBarHeight + 50);
    
    //var graphLabel = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
    var rotateStr = "rotate(-45,"+ xpos + "," + (maxBarHeight + 50) + ")";
    addText(svgGraph, xpos, maxBarHeight + 50, entries[i].name, "x-title", "", "middle", rotateStr);
    
    //svgGraph.appendChild(graphLabel);
    
    xpos += 60;
  }
};

const addGridLinesAndGraphLabel = () => {
  var rootDiv = document.getElementById("root");
  rootDiv.style.display = "flex";
    
  var svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
  svg.setAttribute("id", "svg-graph");
  svg.classList.add("graph");
  
  var xgrid = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
  xgrid.classList.add("grid");
  xgrid.classList.add("x-grid");
  xgrid.setAttribute("id", "xGrid");
  addLine(xgrid, "90", "90", "5", "490");
  svg.appendChild(xgrid);
  
  var ygrid = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
  ygrid.classList.add("grid");
  ygrid.classList.add("y-grid");
  ygrid.setAttribute("id", "yGrid");
  addLine(ygrid, "90", "1805", "490", "490");
  svg.appendChild(ygrid);
  
  var ylabels = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "g");
  ylabels.classList.add("labels");
  ylabels.classList.add("y-labels");
  addText(ylabels, "80", "15", 100);
  addText(ylabels, "80", "131", 75);
  addText(ylabels, "80", "248", 50);
  addText(ylabels, "80", "373", 25);
  addText(ylabels, "80", "500", 0);
  addText(ylabels, "60", "200", "Pass %", "label-title");
  svg.appendChild(ylabels);
  
  addText(svg, "500", "550", "PROJECTS", "label-title");
  
  rootDiv.appendChild(svg);
};

const ReleaseScopeCharts = () => {
  const data = [
    {
      name: 'Transit',
      passed: 20,
      skipped: 50,
      failed: 30,
      untested: 0
    },
    {
      name: 'Access',
      passed: 0,
      skipped: 0,
      failed: 0,
      untested: 100
    },
  ];

  const colors = ['#30D158', '#005EA7', '#FF453A', '#ffcc00'];
 
  const entries = data.map(d => ({
    name: d.name,
    total: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'untested'].reduce(
      (acc, key) => acc + d[key],
      0
    ),
    bars: ['passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'untested']
      .map((key, i) => ({
        value: d[key],
        color: colors[i],
        y:
          key === 'passed'
            ? 0
            : key === 'skipped'
            ? d.passed
            : d.skipped + d.passed,
      }))
      .filter(bar => bar.value),
    }));
        
    addGridLinesAndGraphLabel();
    addBarsToGraph(entries);
    
};

window.onload = () => { ReleaseScopeCharts(); }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.mGraph > svg {
  position: relative;
  left: -60rem;
  top: -.65rem;
}

.mGraph > div {
  position: relative;
  left: -58rem;
  top: -.65rem;
}

.mGraph > text {
  position: relative;
  left: -50rem;
}

.graph .labels.x-labels {
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.graph .labels.y-labels {
  text-anchor: end;
}


.graph {
  height: 600px;
  width: 1200px;
}

.graph .grid {
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-width: 1;
}

.labels {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.label-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  fill: black;
  margin-left: 50%
}

.data {
  fill: red;
  stroke-width: 1; 
}

.bar-count {
  fill: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotateX(0deg)
}

.x-title {
    color: red;
    margin-top: 20%;
    /*transform: rotate(-45deg)*/
};

.content-style {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It was a good exercise ;-)